# How to aim pop-up window correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

Would anyone know how to aim the pop-up window correctly? I'm trying to do it with this code and confirm it as YES, but I feel like it's still targeting me somewhere else, maybe under it. I will be happy for any advice. My code:

```
cy.get('.dx-popup-normal').find('.dx-button-text', { timeout: 5000 }).contains('Yes')
      .within(() => {
        cy.get('.dx-button-text').click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `contains` with a combination of selector and content. Then we are asserting that the element should be visible with a maximum timeout of 5 seconds and then we are finally clicking the button.

```js
cy.contains('.dx-button-text', 'Yes', {timeout: 5000})
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

Comment: thank you! its function!